# "Nontrivial" singular points on the eigencurve?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the Coleman-Mazur-Buzzard eigencurve of some fixed tame level $N$.  Are there any known examples of a singular point $x\in \mathscr{C}$ which lies in a *unique* irreducible component of $\mathscr{C}$?  Certainly the eigencurve can be singular at points where irreducible components of different flavors (e.g., Eisenstein vs. cuspidal, CM vs. non-CM, distinct inertial types at some prime dividing $N$) cross each other.

Comment: Dear David, take $N=11, p=3$. The ordinary family has degree two over the Iwasawa algebra. Let $\Delta$ be the discriminant. Specializing in weight $2$, the ordinary Hecke algebra is $(a,b) \in \mathbf{Z}_3 \times \mathbf{Z}_3$ with $a \equiv b \mod 3$, so $\Delta$ specializes to $9$ times a unit. In weight four, one can check that the ordinary Hecke algebra is $\mathbf{Z}_3[\sqrt{\pm 3}]$, so $\Delta$ specializes to $3$. From this, one sees that $\Delta$ is neither constant nor a square. This implies that there is only one component, and (Weierstrass preparation) that $\Delta$ has a root.

Comment: Dear Sausage, Couldn't this situation correspond to something like
$\mathbb T = \mathbb Z_p[[k]][X^2 - (15 - 3k)]?$ (Here I am changing variables in $\Lambda = \matbb Z[[T]]$ from $T$ to $k$ in some region of weight space, just to make things easier.)  This ring is also just $\mathbb Z_p[[X]],$ with the map to weight space being given by $k = (15 - X^2)/3$, so the ordinary family itself is not singular, it is just that there is ramification in the map to weight space.  Regards, Matt

Comment: P.S.  Probably I should be a little careful if I was working integrally, since there is a division by $3$ in the formula relating $k$ and $X$, but I don't think this will cause trouble on the rigid analytic fibres, which is what the OP is asking about.  

Comment: Or, more precisely, the relevant region of $X$-space in my example  (the region lying over the closed unit $k$-disk), is not the unit $X$-disk, but rather the disk $|X| \leq |3|^{1/2}$.  

Comment: @Emerton: Of course you are correct, I didn't read the question carefully and was thinking of ramification over weight space.

Comment: Dear David, After having SR sign off on my comments, I think it's possible that the answer to your question is "no", that such singular points are not known.  They are not known to me at least, and while I've certainly had conversations about these issues with various experts over the years, unfortunately I don't remember now what I was told in them. If Joel sees this question here, than you might get an answer, since he's thought a lot about these sorts of questions.  If not, perhaps you could ask him directly.  Cheers, Matt

Comment: Dear Matt and SR, Thanks a lot for your comments! SR: It's funny, but I saw that exact Hida family in a talk by Rob Pollack a month or so ago; he explained a new algorithm which e.g. lets you compute a presentation of $\mathbf{T}$ as a $\Lambda$-algebra to some enormous $(p,T)$-adic accuracy. 

Comment: Dear David, that's not *quite* a coincidence; I first heard of that example from Glenn Stevens in 2003 who saw it originally from Rob. Around that time, I computed by hand equations for this Hida family (using the trace formula and Weierstrass preparation) modulo small powers of $(3,T)$, enough to show that $\Delta$ had a unique root $t_0$ in $\Lambda$, but that $\Delta'(t_0) \ne 0$, which shows in this case that the family is smooth. I wondered then about the same question you are asking now, but I'm afraid to say that I don't have any profound thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Hmm how can you detect the non-smoothness? Can it detected by studying the p-adic L-function of the adjoint representation? Anyways David, I looked at your preprints it seems we are working on same/similar problem.

Comment: Dear SR, thanks for your remarks - $N=11$, $p=3$ a really nice example!  Dear Arijit, I think the p-adic adjoint L-function will only detect ramification of the weight map, and might actually be tricky to define at singular points (its definition near a point $x$ relies on choosing a basis for a certain $\mathscr{O}_{\mathscr{C}}$-module locally at $x$). What problems are you working on? Feel free to email me.

Comment: We don't know if the local ring of a component at a point associated to a $p$-irregular weight one point is a regular ring.