# Examples of component crossing between families of modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, hida-theory

Is there a reference that contains explicit examples of component crossing of Hida families at height one primes?  The paper of Emerton, Pollack, and Weston addresses component crossing obtained through level raising.  I am interested in examples caused by other phenomena (e.g. a CM family meeting another CM family coming from different imaginary quadratics or a CM family meeting a non-CM family.)  A question was previously asked that suggests such families exist:

[Example of a non-smooth irreducible component of the generic fibre of a Hida family?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169058/example-of-a-non-smooth-irreducible-component-of-the-generic-fibre-of-a-hida-fam)

I am unable to find examples in the literature, but it's possible that I've looked in the wrong places.

Comment: I asked a question some while back about congruences between CM and non-CM modular forms; this should give some examples.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Sorry for not being more specific.  Such a congruence would give a crossing at a maximal idea.  I am primarily interested in crossings at height one primes.  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interesting example in this [paper](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~eghate/weight1-jntb-final.pdf) by Dimitrov and Ghate, section 7.3.

Answer (score 6):

You can write down explicit examples of such crossing with Eisenstein series.  If one takes the $p$-adic family of Eisenstein series $E^{(p)}_k(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ and the family $E^{(p)}_k(\chi_2,\chi_1)$, then one sees explicitly (just look at $q$-expansions) that these families meet in weight 1 --- i.e. the order of the characters doesn't matter in weight 1.

In the special case when $\chi_1$ is quadratic, $\chi_2$ is trivial and $\chi_1(p)=1$, there should even be some explicit CM family which also specializes in weight 1 to $E^{(p)}_1(\chi_1,1)$ coming from the the quadratic field cut out by $\chi_1$.

Comment: I agree that the constant term of the $q$-expansion of $E^p_1(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ at the cusp $\infty$ is zero, but how we proof that the evaluation of $E^p_1(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ is trivial at the $\Gamma_0(p)$ orbit of $\infty$ (in order to say that $E^p_1(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ is cupsidal overconvergent)?